# How to detect if your custom Call Directory extension is enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, call-directory-extension

I am developing a custom Call Directory extension on iOS 13. I like the containing app to display a nondisruptive message so the user is aware the extension is not currently enabled with a quick hyperlink to the Settings-app so it can enable it quick and easy. However I can't find the API that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CXCallDirectoryManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcalldirectorymanager) and the method

```
func getEnabledStatusForExtension(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
                completionHandler completion: @escaping (CXCallDirectoryManager.EnabledStatus, Error?) -> Void)
```

to see if your extension is enabled with the specific identifier for your extension. Result returns if state is unknown, enabled, or disabled.

*Edit Mark:*
To complete the answer. To open the Settings-app use:

```
CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.openSettings { (error) in
    print("Open Settings")
}
```

Comment: You are the best!